# How do I resolve the CORS:preflight error when configuring a reverse proxy in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use Nginx's reverse proxy to route from blog.example.com to example.com/blog.

The two websites are working independently on different servers.

When I set up the reverse proxy, the admin page in WordPress throws a CORS error and shows as offline.

```
"Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/blog/wp-json/...' from origin 'https://blog.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request."
```

But I don't know how to solve the CORS problem.

I've tried adding and subtracting headers like `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' * always;` to `location / , server{}, location /blog/ , nginx.conf` etc, but it still doesn't work.

Can someone tell me how to work around this?

Here are my server settings now.

Server block of example.com

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;  
    }

    location /en/ {
    rewrite ^([^\?#]*/)([^\?#\./]+)([\?#].*)?$ $1$2/$3 permanent;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' * always;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;

    proxy_pass https://blog.example.com/;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host blog.example.com;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";

    }
}
```

Server block of blog.example.com

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name blog.example.com www.blog.example.com;
    root /var/www/blog.example.com;
    
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;  
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' * always;
    }
}
```